# On duplicate key - update multiple tables

Tags: mysql

How can I update multiple tables with an insert? What I'm trying here doesn't work. Also, how can I add/subtract **u.score** with the difference between a vote variable and the existing v.weight?

```
INSERT INTO votes (userid, publication_id, weight) VALUES (1,2,3)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY 
              UPDATE votes v, users u


            SET v.weight=1
              WHERE v.userid=1
              --TODO: update u.score
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you probably want to use a trigger:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Alternatively, you could encapsulate your initial insert, your logic, and any subsequent inserts into a stored procedure:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html